# Do we always need at least two time points in order to do a fixed effects model?

Tags: regression, fixed-effects-model, cross-section

I have a question concerning fixed effects regression models. I have a cross-sectional data set which only accounts for one year (2017). I want to look at the effect of one individual factor (e.g., gender) on another individual factor (e.g., perception of economy), wheareas those individuals are nested within different countries.

Is it still possible to run a fixed effects model, or does one always need at least $T=2$ time points? And, does it make sense to use fixed effects, since both variables are on the individual level?

Thank you very much in advance for your answer.

Comment: Welcome. So you have a cross-sectional dataset from *one year* and it is comprised of multiple individuals embedded within a series of countries?

Answer (score 0):

You can surely have other fixed effects than unit fixed effects over several time periods.

For example (just one that comes to my mind, there are many others), Geronimus and Korenman, Quarterly Journal of Economics 1992, study the effect of teenage births on economic outcomes such as income relative to needs,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\log(\text{income/needs}_{fs})&=&\beta_0+\delta_0\text{sister2}_{s}+\beta_1\text{teenbirth}_{fs}\\
&&\quad+\beta_2\text{age}_{fs}+\text{other factors}+a_f+u_{fs},
\end{eqnarray*}
To account for socioeconomic effects, they include family specific effects $a_f$, which they can do because they have data for several sisters of one family.

If however, you have $n$ observations, $K$ regressors *and additionally* want to include $n$ observation specific intercepts, that will not work (with an OLS approach), as you will need to fit $K+n$ coefficients to just $n$ observations.